# Can't concat to array state after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

So this is a bit of a tricky problem to explain. Basically, what I do is I query firebase to obtain some information, then I display that information in a list view. This works the first time, but when I refresh the component, my listview only displays the last value that I fetched.

There's no issue with my refresh, all the states are displaying the right information, the console log indicates variable is still the same. But I just can't seem to append to my recipelist state anymore.

```
handleUpdateIndex (selected) {
firebase.database().ref('recipes').orderByChild('custard').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {

    var variable = snapshot.val();
    var first = "variable.";
    var last = " === 0";
    var joined = this.state.unavailable.join(' === 0 && variable.');
    var before = first.concat(joined);
    var final = before.concat(last);

    if (eval(final)){
        console.log(variable)
        this.setState({
        recipelist: this.state.recipelist.concat(
          variable
        )
      })
    }
  });

this.setState({selectedIndex : selected})
}
```

Comment: has you tried to pass a function to setState? it is not recommended to update the state based on the old state. `this.setState((state, props) => {
  return {counter: state.counter + props.step};
});`

Comment: and what do you mean refresh the component? Is it a react rerender? or do you refresh the browser?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you expect your code is supposed to do.  Are you sure you want to use the `child_added` event?  It'll get invoked once for each child at the query location.  Try adding a console log at the top of it to see what it's doing (not inside the `if`).

Comment: yeah i just call componentdidmount again. I will try your fix david

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah basically it outputs a list, it works perfectly on the first attempt, but doesn't when I do it again. I don't think it's anything wrong with firebase.

Comment: Is your recipelist an array or string?

Comment: it's an array   recipelist: []

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    recipelist: [...prevState.recipelist, variable]
  }));
```

Also make sure you are binding handleUpdateIndex in constructor like

```
 this.handleUpdateIndex = this.handleUpdateIndex.bind(this);
```

Comment: i can link you the whole page if you want. Yeah I have binded it already

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've fixed it after a couple hours.

```
var samples = [];
firebase.database().ref('recipes').orderByChild('custard').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {

    var variable = snapshot.val();
    var first = "variable.";
    var last = " === 0";
    var joined = this.state.unavailable.join(' === 0 && variable.');
    var before = first.concat(joined);
    var final = before.concat(last);
    var string = variable.toString();
    if (eval(final)){
        samples.push(variable);
    }
  });
this.setState({
    recipelist: samples
})
```